# Regex won't match hyphens or backslashes

Tags: regex

I have some regex that checks for special characters in a string but even though i've included hyphens and backslashes AND escaped them it still doesn't match

e.g.

```
Regex = '/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[*£#!@$%^&(){}\[\]:;<>"’,.?\/\\`~_+\-=|])^[^-\s]{8,}$/'
```

Strings that don't match but should

```
String\1
Word123!-
```

Comment: `String\1` seems to match. What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: You have `[^-\s]{8,}` for consuming the string.  What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: @dawg I was hoping that would mean minimum 8 characters and no white space?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z].*)(?=.*?[a-z].*)(?=.*?[0-9].*)(?=.*?[*£#!@$%^&(){}\[\]:;<>"’,.?\/\\`~_+\-=|].*)^\S{8,}$/
```

Your issue is `[^-\s]{8,}` and that says *don't match spaces OR hyphens*

If you want the character class for just *no spaces* use `\S`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6agIIZ/1/)